# Numpy 2D array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science, slice

Hope you all are safe and healthy.

I was going through the concept of NumPy 2D array slicing and I came across following syntax which in return giving me an Index error.

```
img_slice[np.greater_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],100) & np.less_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],150)] = 0
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img_slice)
```

Error

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-689f14047e87> in <module>
----> 1 img_slice[np.greater_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],100) & np.less_equal(img_slice[:,:,0],150)] = 0
      2 plt.figure()
      3 plt.imshow(img_slice)
      4 

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

img_slice

```
 [[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

Can someone please explain to me, how img_slice[:,:,0] works?

Thank you in advance.

Stay Home Stay Safe!!!

Comment: If `img_slice` is 2d, then `img_slice[:,:,0]` does not work.  That indexing assume it is 3d, possibly a color image with shape `(h,w, 3)`.

Comment: img_slice[:, :, 0] will attempt to slice a 3D array into a 2D array. The ":" says "all of the indices along this dimension".
The fact that you're getting this error suggests to me that you're attempting to use it in 2D arrays.